# Compiling ApiDemos Android 4.4

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to compile ApiDemos for Android 4.4.

I have fixed the support library not being included issue. 
However, the new resource folder "transition" doesn't compile.

It says invalid resource folder name for folder transition.

For compilation standpoint i can name it "_transition" and eclipse ignores it.
However, after that it doesn't recognise.

R.transition

I am compiling the project with Android 4.4.

I also tried making it run only on Android 4.4 by changing the manifest like below:

```
android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Anyone, else able to compile and run it successfully?

BR,
Jayshil

EDIT: as required

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available     properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
```

Comment: Copy and paste the content of your project.properties here.

Comment: I am just updating my SDK tools as well just for making sure everything is latest. Will update after its done.

Comment: Updated to the latest SDK tools, but still no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have the same problem.Even i creat a new project with the source project, it doesn not work. So i installed the ApiDemo for Android 4.3 for instead and found that the folder transition does not exist in it. So it must be a new feature for Android 4.4.At last,i found the solution that is the version of my Android SDK Build-tools is too old to complie this project.So you need to update your Build-tools.

you can open the Android SDK Manager => install the Android SDK Build-tools of the version 19. =>Add the compatibility library "android-support-v4.jar" to you project.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: I was an Idiot I mentioned i updated but it seems i dint check whether it was 19 or 17. 19 fixes it.

Comment: I install all the versions of the Android SDK Build-tools and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I did as follows. (Windows Eclipse version)

- in Android SDK Manager, I installed Android SDK Build-tools of Rev. 19.
- in Window > Preference > Android I pressed Apply

I don't understand what happened, but it worked to me. :)

If you launch kitkat emulator and try to install it, you'll see "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE", because the emulator already has API Demos.
If you want to check your source, you can delete it and install your source, because the API demo source has different signature and no versioncode.